# $\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{30}n^{61}\right)\pmod{961} \equiv\space?$

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

> What's $$\large\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{30}n^{61}\right)\pmod{961} \equiv\space?$$
>
> $\mathscr{ A)\space404}$
>
> $\mathscr{ B)\space434}$
>
> $\mathscr{ C)\space465}$
>
> $\mathscr{ D)\space496}$
>
> $\mathscr{ E)\space527}$
> $\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}\newcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}\newcommand{\text}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}\newcommand{\root}[2][]{^{#2}\sqrt[#1]} \newcommand{\derivative}[3]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}} \newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}\newcommand{\x}[0]{\times}\newcommand{\summ}[3]{\sum^{#2}_{#1}#3}\newcommand{\s}[0]{\space}\newcommand{\i}[0]{\mathrm{i}}\newcommand{\kume}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}\newcommand{\bold}[1]{\textbf{#1}}\newcommand{\italic}[1]{\textit{#1}}\newcommand{\kumedigerBETA}[1]{\rm #1\!#1}$

What have I tried? I tried to find sum of odd numbers so that I can eliminate odd number or even number choices. Then I realized the mod is odd, so I can't calculate the parity of the sum without using mod. What can I try now?

Comment: Python says $D$, for what it's worth.

Comment: Correct, it's D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$r^{2m+1}+(31-r)^{2m+1}\equiv\binom{2m+1}131r^{2m}\pmod{31^2}$$

Here $m=30,r^{60}=(r^{30})^2\equiv1\pmod{31}$

$\implies31r^{60}\equiv31\pmod{31^2}$

Comment: Very nice! ${}{}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thanks. I should made further generalization  $$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n^{2p-1}\pmod{p^2}$$  OR $$\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}n^{2r+1}\pmod{p^2}$$  for that matter

Comment: May be, may be not? It took me a while to figure out how to use your hint, but I did get there in the end :-)

Answer (score 1):

By Faulhaber's formula,
$$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{30}n^{61}=\frac{1}{62}(B_{62}(31)-B_{62}(0))=\frac12\sum_{k=2}^{62}{62\choose k}B_{62-k}31^{k-1}.$$
By [Von Staudt-Clausen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem), we have
$$S\equiv \frac12{62\choose 2}B_{60}\times31\equiv\frac12\frac{62\times61}{2}(-\frac{1}{31})31\equiv\frac{31}{2}\equiv31\times 481\equiv31\times16\equiv 496\pmod{31^2}$$